# creating a tags like layout in a fragmentlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am looking for a tags section or layout in a fragmentlayout. similar to google+ tags, how to structure or what layout should i have to use to get a tag layout in fragmentlayout. [image]

Comment: you can create your own bitmaps.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045091/android-material-chips/50155934#50155934

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [this](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap) library source. Its really awesome and may be it can help you to customize the tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this lib, it works great for me.

[Android-Cloud-TagView-Plus](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1395#!description)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020 there is offcial implementation in material library: https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/